# Calling method in whereRaw using column names as parameters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need to make a query calling the following method:

```
public function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2) {
  ...
  $d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return $d;
}
```

I've got 'syntax error, unexpected '.'' when trying to add 'latitude' and 'longitude' as parameters:

```
public function show($lon, $lat, $radio) {
  $results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)
                  ->whereRaw( 'radio + ' . $radio . ' <= ' . $this->getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat, $lon, . 'latitude, longitude)');
  return response()->json($results);
}
```

And on this way I got error 500:

```
public function show($lon, $lat, $radio) {
  $results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)
                ->whereRaw( 'radio + ' . $radio . ' <= ' . $this->getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat, $lon, 32, 2));
  return response()->json($results);
}
```

How can I make that query passing $lat, $lon as variables and 'latitude', 'longitude' as values for every register.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public function show($lon, $lat, $radio) 
{   
    $results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)->whereRaw( 'radio + ' . $radio . ' <= ' . $this->getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat, $lon, 'latitude', 'longitude'));   
    return response()->json($results); 
}
```

Comment: As you say, I'm getting the following inside my method: local.INFO: lat1: 51.5134, local.INFO: lat2: latitude.  lat2 and lon2 will be read as Strings by getDistanceFromLatLonInKm, for that reason I am getting error 500